# fading UIImageView transition

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview, transition

I'd like to build a nice background to a view with images fading out & in. BUT, I also would like the animation not to stop.

I was already using this :

```
backgroundUIImageView.animationImages =
[UIImage(named:"testimage1"), UIImage(named:"testimage2")]
backgroundUIImageView.animationDuration = 10
backgroundUIImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0
backgroundUIImageView.startAnimating()
```

Problem : The transitions are not faded

I also tried this :

```
        var UIImage1=UIImage(named:"testimage1")
        var UIImage2=UIImage(named:"testimage2")
        var crossFade = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"contents")
        crossFade.duration = 5.0
        crossFade.fromValue = UIImage1.CGImage
        crossFade.toValue = UIImage2.CGImage
        self.backgroundUIImageView.layer.addAnimation(crossFade, forKey:"animateContents")
        self.backgroundUIImageView.image = UIImage2
```

problem : the animation is not repeated and the code is really ugly & unsafe in my opinion..

Would anyone have any idea/code example about how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just needed to do this myself. I used a combination of NSTimer and CA crossfade. Every time your timer fires you get a nice fade transition. Adjust the length of the animation and the timer interval to set the pace of your animation.

```
func startAnimatingLoadingImage() {
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target:self, selector: Selector("flipImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

and this

```
func flipImage() {
    let cell1 = UIImage(named: "dots1")!
    let cell2 = UIImage(named: "dots2")!
    let cell3 = UIImage(named: "dots3")!
    let cell4 = UIImage(named: "dots4")!
    let cells = [cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4]
    let numCells = cells.count - 1
    let currentImage = cells[currentCell]
    var nextImage: UIImage

    if currentCell == numCells {
        nextImage = cells[0]
        self.currentCell = 0
    } else {
        let x = currentCell + 1
        nextImage = cells[x]
        self.currentCell = x
    }

    let crossFade = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"contents")
    crossFade.duration = 0.25
    crossFade.fromValue = currentImage.CGImage
    crossFade.toValue = nextImage.CGImage
    self.loadingView.layer.addAnimation(crossFade, forKey:"animateContents")
    self.loadingView.image = nextImage
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to write it in SWIFT, but I use this snippet.
To repeat you should add the options `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` and `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`

```
    UIImage * toImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                      duration:0.8f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{
                        self.imageView.image = toImage;
                    } completion:nil];
```